# How to install Doctrine 2 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, doctrine-orm

What is the best way to install Doctrine 2 on Windows 7? I'm running WampServer 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Download**
Visit the Doctrine [download page](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/download).  They give you several options - If you're using a source control tool, which is recommended, you can check out the latest Doctrine 2 from [github](http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2) using git or SVN, or you can download the source directly.

**Step 2: Configuration**
Once you've downloaded Doctrine, there's no installation required - just make sure Doctrine is included either explicitly or in your include path and you can start using it.  To use Doctrine in your app, you need to run a few commands when your app starts up to load and configure Doctrine.  The [Configuration section](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/configuration/en) of the Doctrine documentation walks you through the steps and options for initializing Doctrine in your app.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to get doctrine using tortoisegit but when cloning "git://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git doctrine" as stated in the doctrine guide, it returns the following error:

fatal: remote error:
  doctrine/doctrine2.git doctrine is not a valid repository name

Comment: Just hit the button 'download source' and extract the archive wherever you like, e.g. '..\src\vendor\doctrine'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download complete package you can try [Doctrine All Versions](http://www.doctrine-project.org/downloads/)

Here you found all available versions including nightly builds